# Creating animation of movement along shortest path

Tags: qgis, animation, timemanager, trajectory, movement-data

In my project I need to find the shortest path between different layer points. I did this using the network analysis shortest path tool for single points and OD-matrix tool with QNEAT 3 Plugin for multiple points.

Now I want to show vehicles' movement through the shortest path found. I have already found how to extract the list of points through the shortest path route. How can I use them to represent a continuous movement of vehicles in the route?

Comment: What method are you using to find the shortest path distance?

Comment: @csk I am using the network analysis shortest path tool for single points and OD-matrix tool with QNEAT 3 plugin for multiple points. However, I think that visualizing the shortest path on roads is only possible through the network analysis shortest path tool

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to update your question instead of responding in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it is possible to create an animation along a trajectory with TimeManager as shown in https://anitagraser.com/2017/08/14/movement-data-in-gis-7-animated-trajectories-with-timemanager/.
However, this requires that the trajectory contains temporal information and I'm not sure if QNEAT does provide any travel time information in its output.

Comment: Yes, QNEAT3 does provide total travel time if you choose the 'Fastest path' strategy.